# Reshaping Target Array size for 3DCNN on MNIST dataset - ValueError

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, mnist

I am trying to run a 3DCNN on the MNIST dataset. My code is throwing a ValueError like this:

ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 15000 input samples and 60000 target samples.

And here is my code:

```
import tensorflow
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv3D, MaxPooling3D
from keras import backend as K

batch_size = 128
num_classes = 10
epochs = 12

img_rows, img_cols, img_dep = 28, 28, 4

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

print y_train.shape[0]

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    x_train = x_train.reshape(15000, 1, img_dep, img_rows, img_cols)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(2500, 1, img_dep, img_rows, img_cols)
    input_shape = (1, img_dep, img_rows, img_cols)
else:
    x_train = x_train.reshape(15000, img_dep, img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(2500, img_dep, img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    input_shape = (img_dep, img_rows, img_cols, 1)

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

y_train.reshape(15000, img_dep)
y_test.reshape(2500, img_dep)

print('x_train shape', x_train.shape)
print('x_test shape', x_test.shape)
print('y_train shape', y_train.shape)
print('y_test shape', y_test.shape)

y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv3D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3),
         activation='relu',
         input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv3D(64, (2, 2, 2), activation='relu'))
#model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
          optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
          metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
      batch_size=batch_size,
      epochs=epochs,
      verbose=1,
      validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong? I'm very new to ML and as such this may be a simple error with a simple fix. I could not find any examples online of anyone running a 3DCNN with MNIST data. Thanks!

The traceback message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "3dconvnet.py", line 67, in <module>
    validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
  File "/home/jackson/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 853, in fit
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/home/jackson/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1406, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/home/jackson/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1308, in _standardize_user_data
    _check_array_lengths(x, y, sample_weights)
  File "/home/jackson/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 229, in _check_array_lengths
    'and ' + str(list(set_y)[0]) + ' target samples.')
ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 15000 input samples and 60000 target samples.
```

The output of printing the shapes is:

```
('x_train shape', (15000, 4, 28, 28, 1))
('x_test shape', (2500, 4, 28, 28, 1))
('y_train shape', (60000,))
('y_test shape', (10000,))
```

Edit*  1: added traceback

Edit** 2: added output of printing the shapes

Comment: On which line you got error message? Post full traceback

Comment: Just posted the Traceback

Comment: print out the shapes of x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test  after __all__ reshaping is done and add that to the question.

Comment: Just added the printouts of the shapes

Comment: Is this issue resolved yet?

Comment: You do not need  y_train.reshape(15000, img_dep)
y_test.reshape(2500, img_dep)

Answer (score 0):

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train.shape
Out[3]: (60000, 28, 28)

y_train.shape
Out[4]: (60000,)
```

MNIST dataset consists of 60000 28x28 images with one (not four) channel. Instead of this code fragment

```
if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    x_train = x_train.reshape(15000, 1, img_dep, img_rows, img_cols)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(2500, 1, img_dep, img_rows, img_cols)
    input_shape = (1, img_dep, img_rows, img_cols)
else:
    x_train = x_train.reshape(15000, img_dep, img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(2500, img_dep, img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    input_shape = (img_dep, img_rows, img_cols, 1)
```

you need

```
if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(-1, 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols)
else:
    x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(-1, img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)
```

because image depth (count of color channels) = 1. Also, you doesn't needs

```
y_train.reshape(15000, img_dep)
y_test.reshape(2500, img_dep)
```

Comment: But would that allow me to run a 3D ConvNet on it? I thought you needed a 5D Tensor to do that?

Comment: I need the dimensions of the input to be 5, not 4 to use the Conv3D. Is it even possible with MNIST data?

Answer (score 0):

In my knowledge 3d CNN is used for Volumetric data or temporal image data.
To use in the mnist dataset, somehow u need to convert it into a 5d tensor. Your main error is that x train is of size 25000 and y train is 60000.
This is the problem. Hope it solves.